# Das ist die Frau, deren Bruder krank ist

Tags: relative-pronoun

I read this sentence today.

> Das ist die Frau, deren Bruder krank ist

"deren" is a relative pronoun, in genitive. Relative pronouns in genitive work like this:

- masculine and neutrum: dessen
- femenine and plural: deren

So if "Bruder" is masculine, why is not using "dessen"?

Answer (score 7):

Because *deren* refers to *Frau* and not to *Bruder*.

The sentence translated to english:

> This is the woman whose brother is ill.

Comment: So you mean that in "Die Frau, deren Bruder ....", both "Die" and "dessen"  refer to the gender of the "Frau" and none to the gender of "Bruder"??

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent Yes. In the case of "deren" and "dessen" gender and singular/plural of the "owner" is important; not of the "owned" object.

Comment: You can see that it has to be the gender of the woman if you make it two separate sentences and turn the relative pronoun into a personal pronoun: *This is the woman. **Her** brother is ill.*